# Sort nested dict on keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have run into a little problem with OrderedDicts and sorting.

Currently I have a dict with the following layout:

```
{"da": {1.0 : [], 1.5 : []}, "en" : {1.2 : [], 1.8 : []}}
```

What I want to do is sort each nested dict on the key value in a descending order.
So the output should look like this:

```
{"da": {1.5 : [], 1.0 : []}, "en" : {1.8 : [], 1.2 : []}}
```

Using OrderedDict proves quite a challenge

```
outputDict = OrderedDict(sorted(inputDict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1].keys()))
```

Which gives me:

```
OrderedDict([('en', {1.2: [], 1.8: []}), ('da', {1.0: [], 1.5: []})])
```

Comment: Well what *is* it giving you? You seem to be sorting the outer dictionary but expecting the inner dictionaries to change.

Comment: You are correct. I will edit it to reflect it correctly.

Comment: `t[1].keys()` will produce a dictionary view (Python 3) or a list of keys *in arbitrary dictionary order* in Python 2. Sorting on either has little meaning.

Comment: Last but not least, it is not clear to me what you mean by *the key value in a descending order*; the keys of `inputdict` are `'da'` and `'en'`, and your expected output puts those in *ascending* order. Your sample code looks at the keys of each contained dictionary, and even those are put in ascending order, it seems, but it is unclear to me if you sorted by the lowest or highest key in either.

Comment: If you wanted to sort the nested dictionaries, you'd have to make *those* `OrderedDict` objects, not the outer dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import collections

a={"da": {1.0 : [], 1.5 : []}, "en" : {1.2 : [], 1.8 : []}}

print {k:collections.OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(),reverse=True)) for k,v in a.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'en': OrderedDict([(1.8, []), (1.2, [])]), 'da': OrderedDict([(1.5, []), (1.0, [])])}
```

Comment: This gave me what I want. Thanks